# What Version Control Software Would Be Best For An HTML/CSS/JavaScript only site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, version-control

What Version Control Software is the easiest to setup and use.  It will only be used for two of us both working on a HTML/CSS/JavaScript only site.

We are both using Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git in combination with GitHub would be easy, powerful, and clean. Plenty of documentation on it.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly any open source SCM will do, but for something relatively small you might want to try [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org).

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a linux or MacOS, [Git](http://git-scm.com/) is going to be the easiest to use.  For windows, you could try  [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org).  They are both powerful but simple to set up and use.  For a small project, they are going to be a lot easier than subversion or CVS.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest bitbucket.. just Google it :) they are very good and it took just a couple of hours for me to learn it from 0 to 100. It uses mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer [Git](http://git-scm.com/). Best for most usecases.

Answer (score 0):

Any of them will be fine.

Please don't use CVS, though - it is little more than a toy (note to anyone who wants to disagree: I know all about CVS. The mere fact that it was long the de facto standard does not mean that it was ever a good idea).

If you are familiar with CVS, SVN is superficially similar, but tracks changes to the project rather than individual files. It is the main free, centralised VCS. It is only suitable if you have a central place to keep your single code repository.

Distributed version control systems are suitable for users who have no central place (in your case, you could push changes to each other's repositories), and also suitable for maintaining a central repository. GIT and Mercurial (hg) are the main systems now in use. In practice, they are just as easy to use in "normal" usage as SVN, but make it much easier to deal with merging and creating branches.

If you have anyone around who has already used a version control system (other than CVS), just use whatever they recommend, because it will be fine.